# Using Data URI or File API for uploading files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have some data in javascript and want to upload the data as a file in forms with an upload field.

Is there a way to use Data URI or files created using the File API for upload fields(i.e. `<input type="file" />`).

It only has to work in the Chrome Browser.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking you cannot set the value of an `<input type="file">`, so I'm not sure if what you want is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. the `<input type='file'>` is not customizable for security concern.